# Vertically aligning search bar in navigation

Tags: html, css, centering

I need the search bar to be vertically aligned in the nav so it's not as close to the bottom.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: black;
}

#searchtxt,
.searchtxt {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-right: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 3px;
  outline: none;
  width: 250px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

#search,
.search {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

nav {
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #efefef;
}

nav a {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="albums.html">Albums</a>
  <a href="artists.html">Artists</a>
  <!--dropdown
     AC/DC
     Led Zeppelin
     Kansas-->
  <a href="submit.html">Submit</a>
  <input type="textbox" placeholder="Find an Album" class="searchtxt" /><input type="submit" value="Search" class="search" />
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css.
Remove fixed height on nav and padding-top - height: 30px;padding-top: 10px;

```
nav a {
    /** remove **/
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;

    /** add **/
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```